# Pre-commit flake8 with setup.cfg in subfolder

Tags: pre-commit-hook, flake8, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I use `flake8` with a bunch of plugins (`flake8-docstrings`, `flake8-isort`, `flake8-black`).  I have them all pre-installed into a `venv`.

My repo to be checked with `pre-commit`:

- Root folder has two packages
- Each has its own

  - `pyproject.toml` (configures `black` and `isort`)
  - `setup.cfg` (configures `flake8` and `pydocstyle`)

```
├── foo
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── (the package)
├── bar
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── (the package)
└── venv
```

I want to invoke `flake8` via `pre-commit` for the two packages.

Here's how I do it currently:

```yaml
---
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: flake8-foo
        name: Run flake8 in foo package
        entry: bash -c "cd foo && flake8"
        language: python
      - id: flake8-bar
        name: Run flake8 in bar package
        entry: bash -c "cd bar && flake8"
        language: python
```

When I run `pre-commit run --all-files` and there's an error in `foo`, it prints the same output many times:

```
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
./path/in/foo/to/file.py:49:1: D401 First line should be in imperative mood
```

1. Is there a better way to go about this?

   - No, I am not open to splitting up the packages into their own repos
2. How can I have the error message only print once?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`pre-commit` by design operates on *files*, it also is optimized to batch runs of linters against files into multiple processes

what's happening here is your configuration is running several invocations (~1 per processor) of `bash -c "cd bar && flake8" file1 file2 file3` etc. etc.

fortunately there's a setting you can use to fix this for you:

- [`pass_filenames: false`](https://pre-commit.com/#hooks-pass_filenames)

with that:

```yaml
---
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: flake8-foo
        name: Run flake8 in foo package
        entry: bash -c "cd foo && flake8"
        language: python
        pass_filenames: false
        files: ^foo/
        types: [python]
      - id: flake8-bar
        name: Run flake8 in bar package
        entry: bash -c "cd bar && flake8"
        language: python
        pass_filenames: false
        files: ^bar/
        types: [python]
```

that said, you're losing most of the benefits of the framework by going to a `repo: local` hook:

- pre-commit isn't managing the installation of the tools (each of your developers has to install the tool separately and at a particular version)
- any filename-based optimizations aren't happening

  - if you only change one file, you're currently linting your whole repository **twice**
  - during merge conflicts, pre-commit optimizes which files to run (not the whole repo)
  - and more

what I'd suggest instead for your monorepo setup is to still call flake8 in the normal way but utilize `--config` such that it works against your sub-repos:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 3.8.4
    hooks:
    -   id: flake8
        name: flake8 ./foo/
        alias: flake8-foo
        files: ^foo/
        args: [--config, foo/setup.cfg]
    -   id: flake8
        name: flake8 ./bar/
        alias: flake8-bar
        files: ^bar/
        args: [--config, bar/setup.cfg]
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit and the current maintainer of flake8

Comment: Thank you for both directly answering my question and providing a better overall solution @AnthonySottile!  You're doing great things for the software community